# Laravel 9 - ERROR: Auth guard [ admin] is not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I'm trying to create an Admin Login in `Laravel Jetstream`. I've created a separate `admins` table to store the login data. However, I get an error saying `Auth guard [ admin] is not defined` when I try to access the admin login page through `http://localhost:8000/admin/login`.

I tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` commands, but they didn't solve the issue.

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
],

'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins', 
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
],
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['admin:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/login', [AdminController::class, 'loginForm']);
    Route::post('/login', [AdminController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.login');
});


Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum, admin', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum, web', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

**AdminController**

```
public function loginForm()
{
   return view('auth.login', ['guard' => 'admin']);
}
```

**AdminRidirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect($guard . '/dashboard');
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

**LoginResponse.php**

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
        : redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated::class,

        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

**FortifyServiceProvider.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Actions\Fortify\AttemptToAuthenticate;
use App\Actions\Fortify\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->when([AdminController::class, AttemptToAuthenticate::class, RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class])

        ->needs(StatefulGuard::class)
        ->give(function () {
            return Auth::guard('admin');
        });
}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ isset($guard) ? url($guard.'/login') : route('login') }}">
    @csrf
    ..............
</form>
```

**AdminStatefulGuard.php**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

interface AdminStatefulGuard extends Guard
{
    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return bool
     */
    public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false);

    /**
     * Log a user into the application without sessions or cookies.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function once(array $credentials = []);

    /**
     * Log a user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return void
     */
    public function login(Authenticatable $user, $remember = false);

    /**
     * Log the given user ID into the application.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|bool
     */
    public function loginUsingId($id, $remember = false);

    /**
     * Log the given user ID into the application without sessions or cookies.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|bool
     */
    public function onceUsingId($id);

    /**
     * Determine if the user was authenticated via "remember me" cookie.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function viaRemember();

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function logout();
}
```

Comment: run the command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @N69S I tried. But it didn't work

Comment: try changing `'middleware' => ['admin:admin']` to `'middleware' => ['auth:admin']`

Comment: I would imagine it's the space here `auth:sanctum, admin`, try removing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove space before middleware parameter at web.php

Remove space before admin at 'auth:sanctum, admin'